# Unable to retrieve data from Cloud Firestore using queries

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to retrieve a collection of data from my Cloud Firestore, so that I can arrange the data in a "Bootstrap" Table, displaying the name and the score from the Firestore documents.[FireStore Layout Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0lRJ.png)

I have created a reference to the user collection and queried this to obtain data, however when I run this it throws an exception "Uncaught ReferenceError: querySnapshot is not defined".

```
<script>
var usersCollectionRef = db.collection("users"); //Creates a reference to the Users collection
var query = usersCollectionRef.orderBy("score", "desc").limit(10); //Creates a query based on the collection
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) { //If query is needed
            if (querySnapshot.empty) { //Check whether there are any documents in the result
                console.log('no documents found');
            } else {
                    querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
                        var name =      documentSnapshot.data().name;
                        var score =         documentSnapshot.data().score;
                        console.log(name + score);          
                    });
            }
});
</script>
```

My aim is to retrieve all of the documents inside the user collection, order and sort them using the inbuilt .limit and orderBy methods, then store them in an array so that they can be displayed using a "Bootstrap" table.
`var query = usersCollectionRef.orderBy("score").limit(10); //Selects the 10 highest scoring player's documents`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note for potential readers: the fist part of the answer corresponds to the initial question of the OP, before it was edited.*

You have to put the second part of your code within the `then()` function, as below.
This is because `get()` returns "a promise that will be resolved with the results of the query."  (see the Ref https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get)

```
var usersCollectionRef = db.collection("users"); //Creates a reference to the Users collection

var query = usersCollectionRef.where("name", "==", "Steeve"); //Creates a query based on the collection

query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) { //Call get() to get a QuerySnapshot

            if (querySnapshot.empty) { //Check whether there are any documents in the result
                console.log('no documents found');
            } else {
                    querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
                        //Not necessary to do that  -> return documentSnapshot.data();
                        console.log(documentSnapshot.data().name); 
                    });
            }

});
```

---

EDIT following your comment:

In case you would have several documents for a given name which hold a different score (in a number field `score`), you could get the total score like that:

```
var usersCollectionRef = db.collection("users"); //Creates a reference to the Users collection

var query = usersCollectionRef.where("name", "==", "Steeve"); //Creates a query based on the collection

query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) { //Call get() to get a QuerySnapshot

    var score = 0;

    if (querySnapshot.empty) { //Check whether there are any documents in the result
        console.log('no documents found');
    } else {
        var data = querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
            //Not necessary to do that  -> return documentSnapshot.data();
            console.log(documentSnapshot.data().name);
            score += documentSnapshot.data().score;
        });
    }

    console.log(score);

});
```

---

EDIT after edit of the original post

Do like that

```
var query = usersCollectionRef.orderBy("score", "desc").limit(10); //Creates a query based on the collection
query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) { //If query is needed
            if (querySnapshot.empty) { //Check whether there are any documents in the result
                console.log('no documents found');
            } else {
                var nameArray =  Array.from(querySnapshot.docs, x => x.data().name);
                console.log(nameArray);

                var scoreArray =  Array.from(querySnapshot.docs, x => x.data().score);
                console.log(scoreArray);
            }
});
```

Explanations:

- querySnapshot.docs returns "An array of all the documents in the QuerySnapshot." (See Ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs)
- Then you use Array.from() to create the two arrays (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! I added two variables in order to record the name and score from the documents, but is there a way to iterate these into an array? I tried using a for loop with the length of the querySnapshot.docs but it didn't seem to work

Comment: You don't need any extra loop: in `querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {})` you are actually looping on all the documents which are returned by the query (i.e. for which name = Steeve)

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained that too well, I have since changed the query to retrieve all documents and sort by score. So at the moment the console prints out the 10 documents with the highest score and their name too. What I'm trying to do is add the 10 highest scores to a score[10] array and the 10 names to a name[10] array.

Comment: @LukeAlexanderThompson Can you edit your original post with the new code?