# How do you read data from firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to learn how to use firestore.

The [google documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart?authuser=0) says to try this format:

```
db.collection("users").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
});
```

So, I used that to do this (changing the db to fsDB and "users" to "newsletters"

```
fsDB.collection("newsletters").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
    });
});
```

When I try this, I get an error that says querySnapshot is not defined. Screen shot of error message is attached.

[image]

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154113/unable-to-retrieve-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-queries) and tried its suggestion as follows:

```
fsDB.collection("newsletters").query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) { 

                            if (querySnapshot.empty) { 
                                console.log('no documents found');
                            } else {
                                    querySnapshot.docs.map(function (documentSnapshot) {
                                        console.log(documentSnapshot.data().name); 
                                    });
                            }

                        });
```

This attempt generates a parsing error with the if statement, but I can't find a way to solve that either.

This must have a simple solution, but I can't figure out how to get a record from the database.

NEXT ATTEMPT

I tried moving the code above the return statement and putting in inside a variable as follows shown in the attached screen shot, but it still produces errors as shown. These errors are the same regardless of whether i keep or lose the brackets around querySnapshot.

**ADD STATE**

```
class Fndate extends React.Component {
    state = {
        options: [],
        anzic: [],
        country: [],
        region: [],

    }

    selectCountry (val) {
        this.setState({ country: val });
      }

      selectRegion (val) {
        this.setState({ region: val });
      }

    async componentDidMount() {
        // const fsDB = firebase.firestore(); // Don't worry about this line if it comes from your config.
        let options = [];
        await fsDB.collection("abs_for_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            options.push({
                value: doc.data().title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().title + ' - ABS ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });


        let anzic = [];
        await fsDB.collection("anzic_codes").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
            anzic.push({
                value: doc.data().Title.replace(/( )/g, ''),
                label: doc.data().Title + ' - ANZIC ' + doc.id
            });
            });
        });


            await fsDB
            .collection("newsletter")
            .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
                querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data().email}`);
                }
            );
            });

        this.setState({
            options,
            anzic
        });
    }
```

[image][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3HU8.png)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3HU8.png)

Comment: _"I get an error that says querySnapshot is not defined"_  which line of your code does the error message refer to? I think it's unlikely to be any of the code in your question

Comment: @Phil - it refers to this query statement: querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                                console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
                            });

Comment: What **exactly** is the error message? If you could post a screenshot showing its context, that might help. Are you absolutely certain the code in your question matches your actual code, including upper / lowercase characters?

Comment: @Phil - screenshot attached

Comment: I'm certain. I have been alternating plural and singular case just to make sure there aren't unwritten rules about searching for records. but the same error persists

Comment: That's a linting error (eslint / jslint). Looks like it's not working correctly because `querySnapshot` is most definitely defined

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: The _"no-undef"_ isn't a compilation error. That comes from your static code analysis / syntax checker ~ https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef. For some reason, it's flagging this as a problem but it looks like a false positive

Comment: Might be a silly idea but try removing the parentheses around `querySnapshot`, eg `.then(querySnapshot => { ... })`

Comment: I tried this, but the same error perists

Comment: Looking closely at your screenshot, you appear to have mixed quotes, ie `"newsletters'` (double-quote open, single-quote closed) so I'll ask again, are you certain the code in your question matches your real code?

Comment: That's all the back and forth between singular and plural. they're matching now and still the problem persists. I am 100% sure I have a collection called newsletter. Lowercase.

Comment: I'm curious about the syntax highlighting on line 1003; it shouldn't be all blue. Almost looks like you have an unterminated string expression. Could you provide some more context for the code?

Comment: there is not point to it being in the file its in, I'm just trying to learn how to use firestore to retrieve data. it's in the bottom of a form to create records on a different collection. there are no errors in that form. Which part do you want to see?

Comment: I don't know JSX very well but is the render function really the place to be performing async operations like this? I would try moving this code out of the template and into a more script-y area

Comment: ok - thanks for the tip. ill try exploring more tonight.

Comment: i tried moving it to above the return statement, but still has errors. ill keep looking tonight. thanks for your help

Comment: what's in `fsDB`?

Comment: @JuniusL. - it's my db definition: import { fsDB, firebase, settings } from "../../../../firebase";

Comment: @Mel, try to console.log(querySnapshot) in your code. (which says querySnapshot is undefined). Might be something to do with `fsDB`

Comment: and do you have data in the `newsletters` collection?

Comment: @kkesley -- yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're using React, and I just realized that you're calling the method in question in the `render` method.

try doing it in `componentDidMount`. A reference can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

so your code would be like this:

```
class YourClass extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount(){
      fsDB.collection("newsletters").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
         querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(`${doc.id} => ${doc.data()}`);
         });
      });
   }
   render(){
      return (....your existing jsx....)
   }
}
```

Note that I don't know your class name or how you define your component. But I'm just saying that you need to move your code in the `componentDidMount`.

We couldn't see your entire file. But I'm sure that it's a syntax error (especially with JSX)

Comment: I tried this. I get the same error as defining the variable above the return statement with the other consts. I have it in an async. The same syntax errors as are shown in my post above remain and the console does not log the data.

Comment: actually this works if i put an await tag on it. Thanks for the help

Comment: I can't make plain sense of the example in the react docs for jsx to catch the data and display it. This looks like the bit I'm looking for but I don't know what to do with it in this mount statement:       const list = this.listRef.current;

Comment: @Mel, can you give us your entire component in your question? That way, we can help you to achieve your goal. I'm guessing you need to use `setState` for it. And I don't think you need to use await, but I can't help you further as I couldn't see your component

Comment: Hi @kkesley - state is add above

Comment: @Mel, I think you have used `setState` in your component.. You can reuse that for your "newsletter". Does that mean your question has been answered?

Comment: you answered my original question - I can see data in the console, but I can't see how to work with it so that I can display it in my viewer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of ‘.query’.
and the `.empty` returns `false` if you have data in the collection.
but i wonder, why is `querySnapshot` undefined in your case.

```
db.collection("lessons").get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) { 
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
        querySnapshot.docs.map(function(documentSnapshot) {
        console.log(documentSnapshot.data().name); 
     })
    } else {
    console.log('no documents found');
    }   
});
```

console

[image: console]

Comment: This gives the same error - with the if statement, flagged above. Thanks for trying to help though. There must be a simple way to read data from the database! This is my 2nd day of trying to find out what it is!

Comment: @Phil has answered that part of this mystery above

Answer (score -1):

You can use an automated script for this.
All you need is python and firebase_admin.

1. pip install firebase_admin
2. download https://github.com/harshit0209/firestore_backup
3. now run getData.py script.
4. give it the path of your firebase project private key.
5. now give the document name.